Average with respect to what in the definition of bias in ML?
In many places, we have the following definition for bias:

Average with respect to what in this definition?

depends on the model this refers to, but in linear regression, if I'm not mistaken, is set to be $\hat{y} - \beta \hat{x}$ where $\hat{y}$ is the average "target" in the dataset and $\hat{x}$ is the average value for each feature

See the definition of statistical bias:

Statistical bias is a feature of a statistical technique or of its results whereby the expected value of the results differs from the true underlying quantitative parameter being estimated... The bias of a statistic ${\displaystyle T}$ is always relative to the parameter ${\displaystyle \theta }$ it is used to estimate, but the parameter ${\displaystyle \theta }$ is often omitted when it is clear from the context what is being estimated.

Therefore the average in this definition is with respect to different possible training datasets that could be drawn from the same underlying data distribution. In other words, if you were to train your model multiple times on different samples from the same population, the bias is the difference between the average of these predictions and the true value.
